# How to call the method?

Tags: python, class, random, methods, uniform-distribution

I'm having issues calling the method `aleatorio()` of my class. I need to create a random point `p` using the `aleatorio()` method of my `ponto` class, so I can then use it in my `retangulo` class with the `interior()` method, to basically check if the random point falls in the interior of each of my two rectangles, `r1` and `r2`. However, it seems that I'm not being able to generate the random point `p` that I need.

```
from random import uniform
class ponto:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=float(x)
        self.y=float(y)

    def aleatorio(self):
        ''' Ponto aleatorio com coordenadas 0.0 a 10.0 '''
        self.x=uniform(0.0,10.0)
        self.y=uniform(0.0,10.0)

class retangulo():
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b

    def interior(self,p):
        ''' Verifica se ponto no interior do retangulo '''
        if p.x >= self.a.x and p.x <=self.b.x and p.y >=self.a.y and p.y<=self.b.y:
            return True
        return False

    def area(self):
        return self.a*self.b

a1=ponto(0.0,0.0)
b1=ponto(2.0,2.0)
r1=retangulo(a1,b1)
b2=ponto(4.0,4.0)
r2=retangulo(a1,b2)

p=ponto(0.4,0.9)
p.aleatorio()

d1=0
d2=0
for r in range(10000):
    if r1.interior(p)==True:
        d1+=1
    elif r2.interior(p)==True:
        d2+=1
print(d1,d2)
```

---

As suggested I added the print of `d1,d2` which returns: `0 0`. `d1` and `d2` are supposed to be the number of times my random point falls inside `r1` and `r2`, respectively. I guess `0` either means I'm not generating the random point or that I'm simply not counting the number of times it falls inside correctly, but I'm not sure what the reason is.

Comment: Please provide the evidence of the problem.  For instance, insert a few print statements to show the problem output.

Comment: I have no trouble getting numbers from the call.  What, exactly, tells you that there is no random point?

Comment: The only problem I can find in this code is the entirely useless `for r in range(10000):`.

Comment: Couple things I notice: You don't use the r value in your for loop.  Basically, you're checking the same point in the same two rectangles 10000 times.  Actually, you're checking one of them and only checking the second one if the first one is false.  Your elif line in your for loop should just be an if if you always want to check both rectangles.  You might also want to move your randomize function call (aleatorio) into the for loop to check different points.  Maybe?  It's not clear what you want to happen here.

Comment: @AlanLeuthard is quite correct: this code generates a single point, and then checks 10000 times whether that *same* point is in each of the two rectangles.

Comment: Sorry should've added a bit more context, the for loop is there because i'll then need to calculate the percentage of times it falls inside the rectangle out of 10000. I just didn't write the rest of the code because my problem is both d1 and d2 returning 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your trouble is the looping, not the die rolling.
@AlanLeuthard is quite correct: this code generates a single point, and then checks 10000 times whether that same point is in each of the two rectangles.  Try making a new point every time through the loop:

```
d1=0
d2=0
for r in range(10000):
    p.aleatorio()
    if r1.interior(p)==True:
        d1+=1
    elif r2.interior(p)==True:
        d2+=1

print d1, d2
```

Output:

```
397 1187
```

Does this look better?

Comment: YES IT DOES! Just realised my mistake, you're both right it was in fact always checking the same point, thank you very much :)